# Find prediction of GAM by the estimated equation

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

Consider this code for fitting a GAM and then finding the prediction:

```
library('mgcv')

a0 = 1
a1 = 5

f2 = function(x) x^3

ysim1 = function(n = 500) {
  set.seed(10)
  x1 = runif(n)
  x2 = runif(n)
  e = rnorm(n)
  f = f2(x1)
  y = a0 + a1*x1 + f + e
  data.frame(y = y, x1, x2, f2 = f)
}

df1 = ysim1()
head(df1)

m = gam(y ~ x1 + s(x2), data = df1)
pred1 = predict(m)[1]
```

Here's the prediction:

```
> pred1
       1 
3.846924
```

How can I find this prediction by using the estimated equation formula and `gam` function outputs? Here is an example in case of a linear regression:

```
ysim2 = function(n = 500) {
 set.seed(10)
 x = runif(n)
 e = rnorm(n)
 y = a0 + a1*x + e
 data.frame(y, x)
}

df2 = ysim2()
head(df)

m2 = lm(y~x, df2)

pred2 = predict(m2)[1]
```

The prediction value is:

```
> pred2
     1 
3.5459
```

We can also calculate `pred2` by the estimated equation and `lm` output as:

`coeff[[1]] + coeff[[2]]*df2$x[1]`

What is the above similar code for `gam`?

Comment: Have you tried summary(m)?
https://m-clark.github.io/generalized-additive-models/application.html
or are you looking for coefficients and smooth?
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gam/gam.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have. I know that the coefficients can be given by `m$coeff`. However, I need the values of basis functions for `X`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the so-called Lp matrix, which is the same as the model matrix or design matrix of a LM or GLM but with all basis functions evaluated at the respective values of the covariates. For example:

```r
library('mgcv')

a0 <- 1
a1 <- 5

f2 <- function(x) x^3

ysim1 = function(n = 500) {
  set.seed(10)
  x1 <- runif(n)
  x2 <- runif(n)
  e <- rnorm(n)
  f <- f2(x1)
  y <- a0 + a1*x1 + f + e
  data.frame(y = y, x1, x2, f2 = f)
}

df1 <- ysim1()

m <- gam(y ~ x1 + s(x2), data = df1)

Xp <- predict(m, type = "lpmatrix")

pred <- drop(Xp %*% coef(m))
head(pred)
head(predict(m)) # same
```

```
r$> pred <- drop(Xp %*% coef(m))                                                
r$> head(pred)                                                                  
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
3.846924 2.651058 3.361998 4.927578 1.271078 2.139436 
r$> head(predict(m)) # same                                                     
       1        2        3        4        5        6 
3.846924 2.651058 3.361998 4.927578 1.271078 2.139436
```

Comment: Great! Thanks Gavin. Such a clear and effective demonstration would be welcome - and so long awaited! - for a gam involving either a 'ti' or a 'te' interaction.